# Stata: looping and appending

Tags: stata

I have a situation where I need to import all the files in a directory and append them. My code is this

```
local files : dir "C:\Users\xx" files "*.xls"

local n: word count `files'
tokenize ``files''

cd "C:\Users\xx"

forval  k =1/`n'{

foreach file in `files' {
    import excel "`file'", sheet("Time Sheet") clear

drop in 3

if `k' == 1 {
    di in red `k'
        save "C:\Users\xx\master.dta", replace
    }
    else {
    append using "C:\Users\xx\master.dta"
    }
    save "C:\Users\xx\master.dta", replace
}
}
```

However when I use this code it seems to run an extra loop (* forval  k =1/`n'*) that create duplicate entries. I cannot get rid of that code since I need it for the append command. I was wondering whether there is a way to mitigate this problem.

Comment: The use of backslash here is also [discouraged](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=pr0042).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double loop is causing the problem:

```
local files : dir "D:/Datos/rferrer/Desktop/statatemps" files "test*.xls"

cd "D:/Datos/rferrer/Desktop/statatemps"

local counter = 1
foreach file in `files' {

    import excel "`file'", sheet("Hoja1") firstrow clear

    if `counter' == 1 {
        di in red `counter'
        save "D:/Datos/rferrer/Desktop/statatemps/master.dta", replace
    }
    else {
        append using "D:/Datos/rferrer/Desktop/statatemps/master.dta"
        save "D:/Datos/rferrer/Desktop/statatemps/master.dta", replace
    }

    local counter = 0
}

list
```

You don't use the tokens created by `tokenize`, so you can drop it.

Shorter would be:

```
clear
set more off

local pathdir "D:/Datos/rferrer/Desktop/statatemps"

local files : dir "`pathdir'" files "test*.xls"

save "`pathdir'/master.dta", emptyok replace
foreach file in `files' {

    import excel "`file'", sheet("Hoja1") firstrow clear
    append using "`pathdir'/master.dta"
    save "`pathdir'/master.dta", replace

}

list
```

You might want to read `help quotes` if for some reason you have "weird" file names (and because it's a good read anyway).