# Stata append datasets using foreach and local

Tags: append, stata

I'm trying to append many files in Stata using loop. I've tried this answer: [Stata: looping and appending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29035768/stata-looping-and-appending)

And below is my code.

```
clear
local pathdir "Data\RawData\edd"
local files: dir "`pathdir'" files "test_*.dta"

save "`pathdir'/master.dta", emptyok replace
foreach file in `files' {

    use "`pathdir'/`file'", clear
    append using "`pathdir'/master.dta"
    save "`pathdir'/master.dta", replace

}
```

It just gives me empty space. I'm not really sure what to do. Why doesn't this work? Thank you for any help.

Comment: What do you mean by "empty space". Is the resulting data empty or do you mean the file path expands to empty such that you get an error?

Comment: The resulting data is empty. Nothing appears in the dataset..

Comment: Are you running the code above as continuous block? That is, if you run the loop separately from the lines defining your local file path and your list of files Stata will see the `files` list as empty, but won't tell you as much when running your loop.

Comment: hmm I am running the code as a chunk (I guess that's a continuous block). I'm not running it line by line.

Comment: It was a stupid mistake on my end... I didn't use the full path. Thank you for your comments. I don't know the rule, but should I just delete this post?

Comment: Up to you! There are no answers so you'll be able to delete it. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions)

Comment: Now an upvoted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me just add that looping to append files is not necessary.

```
clear
local pathdir "Data\RawData\edd"
local files: dir "`pathdir'" files "test_*.dta"
append using `files'
save "whatever.dta"
```

Comment: This is the way.

Comment: I usually always append this way, but sometimes it is hard to if you have to filter which files you want and don't want in a folder when there is no straightforward way to do so without looping. Out of curiosity, would anyone know how much slower (assuming it is slower) appending via a for loop is compared to using this local macro method? If it is not substantially slower, I find looping to be more useful at times. If it is a lot slower, then I should stick to finding better ways to compartmentalize .dta's into folders for this method.

Comment: Not sure about speed, my guess is that it's not going to matter very much, it tends to make the code more concise though. If wildcards are not enough to specify the files you want to append, you could also consider constructing the list of files in a loop, instead of appending in a loop.